# Cassandra and Apache Ignite Integration for Write-through and Read-through?

Tags: cassandra-2.0, ignite

I want to integrate apache ignite in-memory feature in apache cassandra. How I can do that ? Is ay plugin avaliable for write-through and Read-throught ? What can be the possible architecture for efficient insertion and retrieval ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you should implement `CacheStore` interface and provide it in `CacheConfiguration`. See [1] for more details and examples.

Also note that there is a Cassandra store implementation in development [2], so very soon this integration will be provided out of the box. You can watch the ticket to track its progress.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistent-store

[2] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-1371